# Can't retrieve form params with Revel

Tags: go, revel

I can't retrieve the form data using Revel. I'm able to retrieve query params though.

I have this controller to test the content of `c.Params`:

```
func (c UserController) SaveUser() revel.Result {
    return c.RenderJson(c.Params) //just for check the content
}
```

When I pass a query param (testkey, value) I get:

```
{
  "Values": {
    "testkey": [
      "value"
    ]
  },
  "Fixed": null,
  "Route": null,
  "Query": {
    "testkey": [
      "value"
    ]
  },
  "Form": null,
  "Files": null
}
```

Everything ok. But when I pass a form param and I don't get any data:

```
{
  "Values": {},
  "Fixed": null,
  "Route": null,
  "Query": {},
  "Form": null,
  "Files": null
}
```

It is a `PUT` request and I'm using Postman to pass form params.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to pass form params as method parameters:

```
// id and nickname are form params
func (c UserController) SaveUser(id, nickname string) revel.Result {
    return c.RenderJson(c.Params)
}
```